# foreach object and async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, express

I'm trying to loop through objects and call a method ("search") which is async and has a callback and when it is done with all objects, write the result object which is resultSet in a json file; but now the problem is since my search function is async writefile does not wait for them to finish and then write resultset to a json file, so it is writing empty objects to a json file; also it is worth mentioning I don't want to use promises; could you please let me know apart from promises what is the best approach to cope with this problem?

```
router.post('/export', function (req, res) {
    Object.keys(models).forEach(function (name) {
        resultSet[name] = [];
        search(param1, name, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(req.host, req.path, err, err.stack);
                res.json(400, err);
            } else {
                resultSet[name] = data;
            }
        });
    });

    var file = "myFile.json";

    jf.writeFile(file,resultSet,function(err){
        console.log(err);
    });      
});
```

Comment: Can you change the search function to take in the whole set of data, and do the looping inside the search function? Then give it a callback, which writes the resultSet after the function is done.

Comment: No it is used in many other places!

Comment: Promises are really the best solution. Why don't you want to use that approach?

Comment: you can create a counter and fired the writeFile when counter says..

Comment: Have you tried using the [async](https://www.npmjs.org/package/async) library to manage this fan-out better? `async.map` does a great job as an asynchronous `forEach` equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change to this:

```
function auxFunc(resultSet){
    var file = 'myFile.json';

    jf.writeFile(file, resultSet, function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    })
}

router.post('/export', function (req, res) {
    var keys = Object.keys(models);
    var counter = 1;
    keys.forEach(function (name) {
        resultSet[name] = []; 
        search(param1, name, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(req.host, req.path, err, err.stack);
                res.json(400, err);
            } else {
                resultSet[name] = data;
                if(counter++ === keys.length)
                   auxFunc(resultSet);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This is a control flow problem..
Callbacks in a loop create a race condition, you have a lot of 'processes' working by it self, so with a counter you would know and detect when all processes have finished, and then you fire the function you need.

Is not necessary to be a counter all the times that you are working with callbacks, depending the situation you may need to process the info and depending on the result fired an action, this could be achieve with a function returning a boolean value, so the trick with callbacks is have **always** a condition in somewhere to control the flow.